# connection string: Node.JS SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Добрый день. Имеется БД, сервер MYSERVER на SQL Server 2012 Express, Windows authentification. Используется Node.JS tools for Visual Studio 2015.

Пытаюсь соединиться из Node.JS:

```
var edge = require('edge');
var params = {
    connectionString: "Server=local\\MYSERVER;Database=mydb_2012;Integrated Security=True",
    source: "Select * from MyTable"
}

var getData = edge.func('sql', params);
var obj, obj_;

getData(null, function (error, result) {
    obj = error;
    obj_ = result;
    if (error)
    {
        console.log(error); return;
    }
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No results");
    }
});
```

В итоге ничего не происходит.

Пробовал ещё mssql, то же самое:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var config = {
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server: 'localhost\\MYSERVER',
    database: 'mybase_2012',
    options: {
       trustedConnection: true,
       useUTC: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Нужен модуль ‘**npm install msnodesql**’*, тогда:

var sql = require('msnodesql');
 var conn_str = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 12.0};Server=localhost\\MYSERVER;UID=;PWD=;Database='mybase_2012';";
 sql.open(conn_str, function (err, conn) {
 if (err) 
 {
 console.log("Error opening the connection!");  return; }
 else  console.log("Successfuly connected");
 conn.queryRaw("SELECT .....

Comment: А если на сервере (рабочей станции) два инстанса SQL server'а (и нужно обратиться к одному из них), тогда правильный синтаксис, видимо, будет, вместо Server=MYSERVER - Server=localhost\\MYSERVER (MYSERVER - имя именно сервера SQL, а не компьютера)?

Comment: Database не должно быть в фигурных скобках? И не должно быть написано Trusted Connection=Yes (или {Yes})

Comment: Нет. npm install msnodesql падает с ошибкой

Comment: Драйвер для MSSQL нужно ставить по-другому.
Здесь написано: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995

Comment: нет, не работает